# Reversing an integer in python is not working

Tags: python, integer, reverse

```
def intreverse(n):   #reverses an integer
    x=0
    d=0
    while(n>0):
        d=n%10
        x=x*10+d
        n=n/10
    return x
```

Why is this code not giving me the reverse of an integer in python?

Comment: What version of Python do you use? In Python-3, `n/10` is floating-point division, not integer division.

Comment: What *does* it give you?

Comment: fyi: you can do this simply with `int(str(n)[::-1])`

Comment: @JulienBernu For practical purposes, you can. For pedagogic, you cannot. But then, nobody would reverse an integer for any practical purpose.

Comment: @ArkaBhowmick, keep in mind that you should validate the answer if it was useful according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, use integer division `//` since `/` will give you a floating point number.

```
def intreverse(n):
    x=0
    d=0
    while n > 0:
        d = n % 10
        x= x * 10 + d
        n = n // 10
    return (x)
```

You can even improve you code by deleting the variable d before the while loop because its value is reassigned when you enter the loop, and you can also use the augmented assignment operator `//=` instead of `n = n // 10`, so you could would be:

```
def intreverse(n):
    x = 0

    while n > 0:
        d = n % 10
        x = x * 10 + d
        n //= 10

    return x
```

Comment: @ArkaBhowmick, please validate the answer if it was useful, keep in mind that that is the way stackoverflow works

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about overflow for a specific integer size you can check if the integer is within say a 32-bit range with a simple if statement [-2^(31), 2^(31) - 1]

```
def intreverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    negative = False
    if x < 0:
        negative = True
        x = x * -1

    res = 0
    while x != 0:
        res = (res * 10) + x % 10
        x = x // 10

        if (res > (2 ** 31) - 1) or (res < -(2 ** 31)):
            return 0

    return (res * -1) if negative else res
```